# Azure SDK v2.7 diagnostics issue is preventing publish/package

Tags: azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2015, azure-diagnostics

I've recently upgraded an Azure cloud service with a web role and worker role to v2.7 of the SDK.

Debugging locally works great.

When I try to publish from within VS 2015 Community, the process fails with an error in the build output:

```
6>Done building project "Cloud.ccproj" -- FAILED.
6>
6>Build FAILED.
========== Build: 5 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Dropping down to msbuild I can see more verbose output and notice the following:

```
Failed to produce diagnostics extension's config for Cloud.WebRoleContent\diagnostics.wadcfgx. 
Error : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input
```

Removing the diagnostics.wadcfgx files from the web and worker roles actually solves this issue and allows me to publish, however I'd prefer to keep my diagnostics.

Adding them back in via the UI lands me at the same error as above.

Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: I am getting the same error. However, I have the connection string mentioned in the answer below. Any other ideas of what might be causing it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't remember the exact error we got but recently we had to add a storage account for diagnostics where previously we didn't. In your ServiceConfiguration you need a line like

```
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="...."/>
```

Comment: You're right, this is all that was missing, thanks!!

Comment: Yes you can also do it from the properties window of the role in the Diagnostics section configure an storage account. Unfortunate error message.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue, but I was not missing the settings in Batavia's solution. I didn't see any other posts with the solution I found, so here you go:

The issue was that there was a file called "diagnostics.wadcfgx" referenced in the csproj of the offending project that was not present in the folder. Removing this item from the proj file resolved the issue.