# Azure Publish or Package fails without errors

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish or package our webrole into Azure, after migrating from SDK 2.5 to 2.7 (2.5 was working fine even though I am not sure if it is related).
This is the error I have from the Build in the Output window :

```
3>------ Build started: Project: MyProject.Azure, Configuration: Production Any CPU ------
4>------ Publish started: Project: MyProject.Azure, Configuration: Production Any CPU ------
4>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "msshrtmi, Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.
4>      Transformed Web.config using E:\Legacy\Main\Azure\MyProject.Front\Web.Production.config into obj\Production\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
4>Done building project "MyProject.Azure.ccproj" -- FAILED.
4>
4>Build FAILED.
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 25 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have searched for an anwer and came up with this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/narahari/archive/2012/03/30/windows-azure-package-creation-or-publish-fails-with-build-failed-message-in-visual-studio-output-window.aspx
where they state that it could be due to an OutOfMemoryException, and the fix is to build on a high end x64 system. I'm building on a core i7 16gig of ram really good computer so I don't think it comes from this. I also installed the windows 7 hotfix that fixes the emulator issue from largeaddressaware switch just in case but it did not help.
Thank you

Comment: Line 3 might give you a clue.

Comment: Can you check in 'Configuration Manager' -> Release or Debug (which ever you are using) and make sure all the projects are trying to build in the same (or intended) 'Platform'?

Comment: check with to change your Application setting with AnyCPU

Comment: I did check, and they all build against the same platform (Any CPU)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I managed to solve the problem and here is how.
Actually, the issue is -even if totally not obvious- related to the diagnostics configuration.
What I did is increase verbosity for MSBuild output :

```
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > MSBuild project build output verbosity : Diagnostic
```

which uncovered this :

```
Failed to produce diagnostics extension's config for MyProject.Azure\diagnostics.wadcfgx. 
Error : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input
```

Then, the fix is to add :

```
<Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString"/>
```

in your ServiceDefinition.csdef and the correct implementations in your csfgs files.
After this, it all builds, packages and publishes.

Now, I am not sure if this question is a duplicate of [Azure SDK v2.7 diagnostics issue is preventing publish/package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31735438/azure-sdk-v2-7-diagnostics-issue-is-preventing-publish-package) because the title of the question in the link's post is already a step forward, and making the connection between this issue and the azure diagnostic configuration is really not that obvious, given visual studio's default minimal output.

Thanks everyone

Comment: Thanks for giving the details of what fixed the issue for you, however I had the exact same error, yet the `<Setting />` already existed in the csdef and the cscfg files. For me, the solution was to delete the Cloud Service project entirely, re-create it and add the existing web and worker roles back in.